# jdbc connection established but didnt print the result in eclipse console

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, oracle

I am new to this forum....

Iam tring to connect java project created in eclipse with oracle database xe,

I followed the procedures as descrided in the following link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fMp63HsIRbc

but it didnt print the result in the eclipse console but it also didnt throw the exception as well

what should be the reason

this is my code

```
package dbmsoracle;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class Jdb {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("jen");
    try
    {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con =        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","murali123");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        String sql="select * from muhil";
        ResultSet rs =st.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println("executing ...");
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getInt(2));
            System.out.println("executed");
            con.close();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("connection failed");
    System.out.println(e);  
    }

    }
```

i have downloaded my jdbc driver

Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2.0.4) JDBC Drivers
ojdbc6.jar
Certified with JDK 8, JDK 7 and JDK 6: ......

and iam using jdk 8

Comment: Does it prints "executing..." ?

Comment: no it just print "jen " and the console gets terminated

Comment: It means your rs is null(mayb because connection is not established or the table itself is empty)

Comment: Run your query in the oracle database editor see that query is running properly or not

Comment: yes it is running

Comment: Ok then your connection of code with database is getting wrong

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the Database connectivity but for future reference, write con.close() outside while loop

Comment: try this statement before while loop and see whether it prints anything or not:   System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+" "+rs.getInt(2));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly check that your connection is establishing with oracle database or not. Here is the connection code try this

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class OracleJDBC {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        System.out.println("-------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------");

        try {

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

            System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

        Connection connection = null;

        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","murali123");

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;

        }

        if (connection != null) {
            System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this is my output:  -------- Oracle JDBC Connection Testing ------
Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!
You made it, take control your database now!

Comment: then connection is established successfully write your query code and run it

Comment: thats what my question is... if i run the code which i posted previously it didnt print anything in the console but it didnt throw any excption. executing.... itself is not printing

Comment: here is my problem (rs.next() ) ... this code is not getting executed ..what should i do

Comment: try this ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from muhil");

Comment: means rs is null and it means that your uery is not returning anything .Mainly this is query issue check your

Comment: here is my problem (rs.next() ) ... this code is not getting executed ..what should i do... the problem is in id i didnt start with it was from  25, i got the output once i changed to 1, 2, 3,... thank you so much once again. onemore question if i want to fetch data with respect to id which may not be continuous what should i do

Comment: which id i didn't get u

Comment: id and reg are the database created by me ... id 24 253 257 reg 245 254 66 this was the table i created earlier for which i didnt get the output then  i changed to id 1 2 3 reg 245 254 66... then i got my output ....what is the reason behind this .... and one more thing i am new to this forum ... how should i accept ur answer

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The problem is your code doesn't catch(SQLException e). Because just catch(Exception e) will not make the exception of sql shown in the console. After doing this, you will probably find the Exception is "No suitable driver found for jdbc".

Then, either you can download the mysql-connector-java and add it to your lib, or if your project is Maven, you can just add dependency in your pom file.

Answer (score 0):

After you used Sql+ for entering database, commit the table. Enter 'commit'(without quotes) on the terminal or either close your Sql+ terminal. In your case, you must have closed the terminal after you changed your id from 24, 253 to 1, 2. That is why it ran properly. Got nothing to do with id starting from 1

Answer (score 0):

first of all go and check if your table has any data or not. It seems you just created this table 'muhil' before writing the above code. i'm pretty sure You must have entered some data as well in your new table. Just make sure you have Committed your transaction in the MYSQL Workbench. Just commit it and try to run your code in eclipse again.